# ASP.NET MVC - Disable button depending on value in database (WebGrid)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a submit button in webgrid, which is sending a row to another table, but I don`t know how to disable this button, when user have done this already.

**First table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Applications] (
    [ApplicationId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicantName]  NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate]      DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [EndDate]        DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [AssistantName]  NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Description]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Approved]       BIT            NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);
```

I created here an "Approved" value, which is changing to "True", when user clicks a button. Then, when **Approved==True** button should be disabled.

**Second table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events] (
    [EventID]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Subject]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [AssistantName]  NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Description]    NVARCHAR (300) NULL,
    [Start]          DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [End]            DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [ThemeColor]     NCHAR (10)     NULL,
    [IsFullDay]      BIT            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventID] ASC)
);
```

**My controller to this action:**

```
        [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Accept(string applicationJSONaccept, Event model)
        {
            Application apl = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Application>(applicationJSONaccept);
            MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities();

            Application app = dc.Applications.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApplicationId == apl.ApplicationId);
            app.Approved = true;

            dc.Events.Add(new Event
            {
                Subject = apl.ApplicantName,
                DepartmentName = apl.DepartmentName,
                Description = apl.Description,
                Start = apl.StartDate,
                End = apl.EndDate,
                IsFullDay = false,
                AssistantName = apl.AssistantName
            });
            dc.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect("ApplicationView");
        }
```

**Webgrid:**

```
@grid.Table(
htmlAttributes: new { @id = "grid", @class = "Grid" },
    tableStyle: "table table-responsive table-bordered",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(columnName: "ApplicationId", header: "Nr"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "ApplicantName", header: "Imię i nazwisko"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "DepartmentName", header: "Oddział"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "StartDate", header: "Od"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "EndDate", header: "Do"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "AssistantName", header: "Zastępca"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "Description", header: "Opis"),
        //Here is this button:
        grid.Column(null, header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Zatwierdź", null, null, new { @class = "accept btn btn-success", @role="button" })</text>)
))
@using (Html.BeginForm("Accept", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "IndexForm2" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="applicationJSONaccept" />
}
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on("click", ".accept", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var application = {};
        application.ApplicationId = row.find("td").eq(0).html();
        application.ApplicantName = row.find("td").eq(1).html();
        application.DepartmentName = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
        application.StartDate = new Date(row.find("td").eq(3).html().substr(6, 4), row.find("td").eq(3).html().substr(4, 2) - 1, row.find("td").eq(3).html().substr(0, 2));
        application.EndDate = new Date(row.find("td").eq(4).html().substr(6, 4), row.find("td").eq(4).html().substr(4, 2) - 1, row.find("td").eq(4).html().substr(0, 2));
        application.AssistantName = row.find("td").eq(5).html();
        application.Description = row.find("td").eq(6).html();
        $("[name=applicationJSONaccept]").val(JSON.stringify(application));
        $("#IndexForm2")[0].submit();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Everything is working fine, row goes to another table, value of Approved is changing, but I`ve problem how to disable this button when Approved==false. Do you know how can I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Tried this, but still doesn`t work.

```
grid.Column(null, header: "", format:
@<text>
    @if (ViewBag.Approved == false || ViewBag.Approved == null) {
        @Html.ActionLink("Zatwierdź", null, null, new { @class = "accept btn btn-success", @role = "button" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Zatwierdź", null, null, new { @class = "accept btn btn-success disabled", @role = "button" });
    }
    </text>)
```

Controller update:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Accept(string applicationJSONaccept, Event model)
{
    Application apl = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Application>(applicationJSONaccept);
    MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities();

    Application app = dc.Applications.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApplicationId == apl.ApplicationId);
    ViewBag.Approved = app.Approved;

    if (app.Approved == false || app.Approved == null)
    {
        app.Approved = true;

        dc.Events.Add(new Event
        {
            Subject = apl.ApplicantName,
            DepartmentName = apl.DepartmentName,
            Description = apl.Description,
            Start = apl.StartDate,
            End = apl.EndDate,
            IsFullDay = false,
            AssistantName = apl.AssistantName
        });
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
    }

    return Redirect("ApplicationView");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, here`s the code:

```
grid.Column(null, header: "Akceptuj", format:

@<text>@Html.ActionLink("✓", null, null, new { @class = "accept btn " + 
(@Html.Raw((item.Approved == true) ? "btn-secondary disabled" : "btn-info")), 
@role = "button" })</text>)
```

That`s all, no css added here, just bootstrap ;)
Thanks for every reply!

Answer (score 0):

you can change the css class ([disabled] selector) based on the value from the database while you are binding your view.

Comment: But how excacly can i do this? Idea seems fine, but I have no idea how to write it.

Comment: while querying your database, you can do case statement like "case when approved then 'ClassApproved' else 'ClassUnApproved' as CssClass. bind this value with some variable say myClass in  your Model and then in your view you can do something like <button class='@Model.myClass' />

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CSS class and remove class whatever your condition, If you need button enable click event then remove class and if you need disable click event then add the class

**Style**

```
.btnDisable{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

In your "IndexForm2" button.

Just add and remove this CSS class your problem solve.

**Try below new code**

```
grid.Column("YourColumnName", format:(item) =>
{
    if (item.Approved == false || item.Approved == null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Zatwierdź", null, null, new { @class = "accept btn btn-success", @role="button" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Zatwierdź", null, null, new { @class = "accept btn btn-success btnDisable", @role="button" })
    }
}
```

Comment: But how exactly can I add class which depends on condition?

Comment: Share your exact which condition you have to need to implement?

Comment: If (app.Approved == false || app.Approved == null) -> button works, else its disabled. I added this to controller and its doing good, but I need to show that button is disabled and make it grey for ex.

Comment: Okay, where is your button code, I see your code and "IndexForm2" this is the form, not a button.

Comment: Here in webgrid (i pasted it under controller)
'grid.Column(null, header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Zatwierdź", null, null, new { @class = "accept btn btn-success", @role="button" })</text>)'

Comment: Check my code I hope this is helpful to you. Also, you need to add a CSS class in your file.

Comment: Mention you're proper column name whatever you have to use.

Comment: Unfortunately your syntax doesn`t work, but I edited it a little bit to get rid of errors, however it still doesnt work. I tried your class and bootstrap "disabled" also, nothing happens. Button is still clickable.

Comment: Add this line 


grid.Column(null, header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Zatwierdź", null, null, new { @class = "accept btn btn-success " + (ViewBag.Approved == false || ViewBag.Approved == null ? "" : "disabled"), @role="button" })</text>)

Comment: Your talking about "disabled" class? It`s in bootstrap styles and normally it works. In your new code i get error in "accept btn btn-success", it says that "Method name is expected"